# Can not add swift Package when "Build Libraries for Distribution = YES" in my Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

Basically, I am building a Framework and I need to add a library into it. The problem is when I change `Build Libraries for Distribution = YES` it shows me a warning

**Module 'ModuleName' was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for 'FramworkName' can't be guaranteed**

Answer (score 0):

Every time you want to import your ModuleName, Add `@_implementationOnly` before `import ModuleName`

it should look like this
`@_implementationOnly import ModuleName`

You can find more details here https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-implementation-only-imports/26996